# How to create sink writer from buffer?

Tags: c++, audio, codec, ms-media-foundation

my implementation of encoder gets as input `.wav` file bytes and gives as output `.mp3` bytes written in out file.

Like this

```
void co_AudioEncoderMF::start_encoding()
{
...
    IMFSinkWriter * sink_writer = nullptr;
    
    //Create sink writer
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
        L"D:\\buffer\\del\\out\\test_out.mp3",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &sink_writer
    );
...

    // Add the stream
    hr = sink_writer->AddStream(
        ouput_media_type,
        &dwWriterStreamIndex
    );

    // Set input media type
    hr = sink_writer->SetInputMediaType(
        dwWriterStreamIndex,
        input_type,
        NULL
    );

    // Tell the sink writer to accept data
    hr = sink_writer->BeginWriting();

...

    hr = sink_writer->WriteSample(
            dwWriterStreamIndex,
            pSample
        );
...
}
```

So, I create a IMFSinkWriter then add it to the straem + set mediatype and then I can write encoded bytes to out file `L"D:\\buffer\\del\\out\\test_out.mp3"`.

Problem here is that I don't want to write encoded data to out file I need to get it as a buffer.

I see there is another possible method

```
STDAPI MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(
    _In_ IMFMediaSink *pMediaSink,
    _In_opt_ IMFAttributes *pAttributes,
    _Out_ IMFSinkWriter **ppSinkWriter );
```

So, as far as I understood it takes pointer on `IMFMediaSink` and out on `IMFSinkWriter` from this point I got that I can make an implementation of `IMFMediaSink` interface which would create `IMFSinkWriter` and set it up when `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` method would be called. *(but I am not sure about that this is a right way to write encoded data in buffer)*.

So, I made an implementation of `IMFMediaSink`

```
#include "co_MediaSink.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "co_SinkWriter.h"

co_MediaSink::co_MediaSink()
{
}

co_MediaSink::~co_MediaSink()
{
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)
{
    printf("HERE");
    *ppvObject = new co_SinkWriter();
    return S_OK;
}

ULONG co_MediaSink::AddRef(void)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return 1;
}

ULONG co_MediaSink::Release(void)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return 1;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::GetCharacteristics(DWORD * pdwCharacteristics)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::AddStreamSink(DWORD dwStreamSinkIdentifier, IMFMediaType * pMediaType, IMFStreamSink ** ppStreamSink)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::RemoveStreamSink(DWORD dwStreamSinkIdentifier)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::GetStreamSinkCount(DWORD * pcStreamSinkCount)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::GetStreamSinkByIndex(DWORD dwIndex, IMFStreamSink ** ppStreamSink)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::GetStreamSinkById(DWORD dwStreamSinkIdentifier, IMFStreamSink ** ppStreamSink)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::SetPresentationClock(IMFPresentationClock * pPresentationClock)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::GetPresentationClock(IMFPresentationClock ** ppPresentationClock)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT co_MediaSink::Shutdown(void)
{
    printf("HERE");
    return S_OK;
}
```

Usage ::

```
    IMFSinkWriter * sink_writer = nullptr;
    co_MediaSink media_sink;
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(&media_sink, nullptr, &sink_writer);
```

So, here with a debug I see that after this `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` method was called, next debug break point a get in `co_MediaSink::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)` method where I need to set (I think) my `IMFSinkWriter` implementation to this out pointer `ppvObject` like this `*ppvObject = new co_SinkWriter();`, but then I get an error

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF95B4F8317 (mfreadwrite.dll) in co_Convert.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

So, there are actually two questions, first is a right way was chosen in order to write in buffer and second - if yes, what is a problem with `Access violation`?

Comment: You could use the source reader to get mp3 encoded buffer. You don't need to implement custom interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have byte stream implemented to accept the data (you are already familiar with `IMFByteStream` concept from your development on the source end)
2. Have [`MFCreateMP3MediaSink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemp3mediasink) (this is the key API for the mentioned task) create an implementation of `IMFMediaSink` for MP3 stream
3. `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` will create an `IMFsinkWriter` on top of this media sink, and you are already aware how to work with sink writers

This way you could write to sink writer and accept parts of MP3 byte stream on the other end.

Comment: There are a few questions : I don't get an idea to create `IMFByteStream`, I can create stream on data that I have, but how I can create a stream on data that I am just going to retrieve? Only way I see here according to your answer is to create a custom implementation of `IMFByteStream` then pass it to `MFCreateMP3MediaSink` get `IMFMediaSink` as out param (not my custom), and then pass it to `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` and finally get `IMFSinkWriter` as out param. I understand it like, when I write to `IMFSinkWriter` it will pass all bytes to my custom `IMFByteStream`, right?

Comment: Correct. Also one thing to add to the above: you can implement also implement `IStream` or maybe even use one of existing implementations and use `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream` on top of if to add one more layer but avoid `IMFByteStream` implementation yourself (makes sense if you don't want to mess with asynchronous calls).

Comment: I faced a problems with `IStream` implementation, could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/q/65458867/5709159