# How to make implementation of IStream correctly (MediaFoundation)?

Tags: c++, audio, codec, ms-media-foundation

General idea is to get a `IMFSinkWriter` that will write a data to the buffer. There is such an implementation

```
bool co_AudioEncoderMF::start_encoding_to()
{
    bool result = false;
    co_Stream stream;
    IMFByteStream * byte_stream = nullptr;
    IMFMediaSink * media_sink = nullptr;
    IMFSinkWriter * sink_writer = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream(&stream, &byte_stream);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && byte_stream != nullptr)
    {
        hr = MFCreateMP3MediaSink(byte_stream, &media_sink);
    }
    
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && media_sink != nullptr)
    {
        hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(media_sink, nullptr, &sink_writer);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && sink_writer != nullptr)
    {
        result = start_encoding_to(sink_writer, m_source_reader);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here I created a class `co_Stream` that implement `IStream` (a minimal implementation, just for test)

**co_Stream.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <ObjIdlbase.h>
#include <vector>

class co_Stream: public IStream
{
    //Constructors
public:
    co_Stream();
    ~co_Stream();

    //Public Methods
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [iid_is][out] */ _COM_Outptr_ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject) override;

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) override;

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) override;

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Read(
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_writes_bytes_to_(cb, *pcbRead)  void *pv,
        /* [annotation][in] */
        _In_  ULONG cb,
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_opt_  ULONG *pcbRead) override;

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Write(
        /* [annotation] */
        _In_reads_bytes_(cb)  const void *pv,
        /* [annotation][in] */
        _In_  ULONG cb,
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_opt_  ULONG *pcbWritten) override;

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Seek(
        /* [in] */ LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwOrigin,
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_opt_  ULARGE_INTEGER *plibNewPosition) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSize(
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER libNewSize) override;

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CopyTo(
        /* [annotation][unique][in] */
        _In_  IStream *pstm,
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER cb,
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_opt_  ULARGE_INTEGER *pcbRead,
        /* [annotation] */
        _Out_opt_  ULARGE_INTEGER *pcbWritten) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Commit(
        /* [in] */ DWORD grfCommitFlags) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Revert(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LockRegion(
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset,
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER cb,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwLockType) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE UnlockRegion(
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset,
        /* [in] */ ULARGE_INTEGER cb,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwLockType) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Stat(
        /* [out] */ __RPC__out STATSTG *pstatstg,
        /* [in] */ DWORD grfStatFlag) override;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Clone(
        /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IStream **ppstm) override;

    //Private Members
private:
    LONG m_cRef; // Reference count.
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_buffer;
    long m_buf_position = 0;
};
```

co_Stream.cpp

```
#include "co_Stream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <mfplay.h>

co_Stream::co_Stream()
{
    m_cRef = 0;
}


co_Stream::~co_Stream()
{
}

HRESULT co_Stream::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)
{
    if (riid == IID_IMFGetService)
    {
        *ppvObject = (LPVOID)this;
        AddRef();
        return NOERROR;
    }
    
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG co_Stream::AddRef(void)
{
    InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
    return m_cRef;
}

ULONG co_Stream::Release(void)
{
    InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
    return m_cRef;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Read(void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG * pcbRead)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    
    if (!m_buffer.empty() && m_buffer.size() < cb)
    {
        memcpy(pv, &m_buffer[0], cb);
        return NOERROR;
    }

    return ERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Write(const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG * pcbWritten)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;

    m_buffer.resize(cb);
    memcpy(&m_buffer[0], pv, cb);

    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Seek(LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove, DWORD dwOrigin, ULARGE_INTEGER * plibNewPosition)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::SetSize(ULARGE_INTEGER libNewSize)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::CopyTo(IStream * pstm, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, ULARGE_INTEGER * pcbRead, ULARGE_INTEGER * pcbWritten)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Commit(DWORD grfCommitFlags)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Revert(void)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::LockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, DWORD dwLockType)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::UnlockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, DWORD dwLockType)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Stat(STATSTG * pstatstg, DWORD grfStatFlag)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Clone(IStream ** ppstm)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}
```

The idea is that this method `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream` will take my implementation of `IStream` and return as out param `IMFByteStream` then I need to create a sink and finally sink writer. Then every time I'll call writer I get these bytes in my `IStream` implementation for further usage.

But instead after I call `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream` and pass my implementation of `IStream` as a param I get `IMFByteStream` - null as a out param.

In debug I see that in `IStream` implementation I get a call of `QueryInterface` -> `AddRef` -> `Read()` -> `Release()`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

There is my current implementation

```
#include "co_Stream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <mfplay.h>

co_Stream::co_Stream()
{
    m_cRef = 0;
}


co_Stream::~co_Stream()
{
}

HRESULT co_Stream::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)
{
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG co_Stream::AddRef(void)
{
    InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
    return m_cRef;
}

ULONG co_Stream::Release(void)
{
    InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
    return m_cRef;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Read(void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG * pcbRead)
{
    //This method is redundant in current implementation because it is needed only to write in buffer.
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Write(const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG * pcbWritten)
{
    m_buffer.resize(cb);
    memcpy(&m_buffer[0], pv, cb);

    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Seek(LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove, DWORD dwOrigin, ULARGE_INTEGER * plibNewPosition)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::SetSize(ULARGE_INTEGER libNewSize)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::CopyTo(IStream * pstm, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, ULARGE_INTEGER * pcbRead, ULARGE_INTEGER * pcbWritten)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Commit(DWORD grfCommitFlags)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Revert(void)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::LockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, DWORD dwLockType)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::UnlockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset, ULARGE_INTEGER cb, DWORD dwLockType)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Stat(STATSTG * pstatstg, DWORD grfStatFlag)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}

HRESULT co_Stream::Clone(IStream ** ppstm)
{
    std::cout << "HERE" << std::endl;
    return NOERROR;
}
```

When I get a call on my method `co_AudioEncoderMF::start_encoding_to()` (above in my question  co_AudioEncoderMF::start_encoding_to) I get a call at `seek` and `stat`, but I don't get an idea how to implement in in case if I need to make a buffer implementation (`std::vector<unsigned char> m_buffer`).

But anyway currently I don't get any crash or errors, but also I am not getting call on my `Write` method.

Below in y code I have such a method

```
...
                hr = sink_writer->WriteSample(
                    dwWriterStreamIndex,
                    pSample
                );
...
```

I see that `pSample` data exist as well as `dwWriterStreamIndex` has a value, but when this method invoke I don't get a `Write` call in my implementation of `co_Stream`

Comment: You should not return NOERROR from a method if you do nothing in it, except the one when it's not specifically required to do anything (like Commit). Are you sure no other method is called? Also, check if pcbRead is passed non null, if it is, you *must* write how many bytes where read, same for pcbWritten

Comment: Wrong IID in QueryInterface to start with.

Comment: @SimonMourier what should it be if not a `NOERROR`? yes, pcbRead that I get as param in `Read` method is not null, but I didn't get `you must write how many bytes where read`? As far as I understand `IStream` I need only as part of `Write` implementation, because I don't need to read nothing I just need to get encoded written bytes

Comment: @RomanR. but when I try debug it, I see that after I call this method `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream` I immidiately get call to this `QueryInterface` method of my implementation of `IStream` and `REFIID riid` that I get as a param is `IID_IMFGetService` that is it. But you say it is not correct?

Comment: Your implementation of QueryInterface is obviously incorrect. While this is not necessarily the only show stopper there, it can easily be at this particular point. You shuld either return E_NOINTERFACE for this IID, or instead return correct pointer as *ppvObject. Also you should retrun proper pointer for IID_IStream which you are not doing, but again there is n oproof you have to do this at thi sparticular point.

Comment: Long story short just return `E_NOINTERFACE` there. Chances are high you will stop seeing following `Read` call then too, and you will be able to move forward.

Comment: You did nothing in react to comments , what do you expect from the bounty?

Comment: @SimonMourier sorry, added to the question my final implementation

Comment: Your implementation is still wildly incorrect. I don't know what methods are called or not (do you?), but you should never return NOERROR when a method doesn't do what's it's supposed to. Also, like I said, `Write` is missing something like `if (pcbWritten) *pcbWritten = writtenCount`. Otherwise, why don't you use something like SHCreateMemStream https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream

Comment: @SimonMourier but should I return if not `NOERROR`? and about - why I use IStream implementation instead of SHCreateMemStream, because finally I need to get access to the buffer. I need that this method `sink_writer->WriteSample` will write encoded bytes to my buffer

Comment: First thing is to debug to check what's called and what's not. Return E_NOTIMPL on method that you reasonably choose to not implement. However, even when not implementing, you're supposed to clear out parameters, eg: `Seek(...) if (plibNewPosition) *plibNewPosition = 0; return E_NOTIMPL;` as for SHCreateMemStream you can access the created stream and read it out, or use CreateStreamOnHGlobal